# How to use both pageStoragekey and uniqueKey in a same widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, key

Any way to using two keys like pagestorage and unique key in a same widget, because I want to achieve both state maintain(page scroll state) and uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation to generate a unique string as the PageStorageKey argument to generate a unique PageStorageKey.

If this doesn't address your question, please supply a short example that illustrates your need.

```
var _someUniqueValue = 10;

Card(
          key: PageStorageKey<String>(
              'Unique PageStorageKey $_someUniqueValue'),
...
)
```